# using if statement to compare a combo box value with two text boxes value

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, combobox, operators

I'm using C# winforms
I have a form with combobox called `cmbExport` and two textboxes `txtDateSend` and `txtSendNum`
The combobox get its data from a stored procedure `GET_ALL_EXPORT_WITHNULL`

```
cmbExport.DataSource = cmp.GET_ALL_EXPORT_WITHNULL(); 
cmbExport.DisplayMember = "side";   
cmbExport.ValueMember = "ID_EXPORT";  
cmbExport.SelectedValue = "6";
```

When the user NOT choose certain values from the combobox and one of the textboxes are empty a meesage box appear

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmbExport.SelectedValue); //Its already integer but the code didn't accept int x = cmbExport.SelectedValue; ???

string ds = txtDateSend.Text;
string sn = txtSendNum.Text;

if ((x != 6 || x != 42 || x != 1042) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sn))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("you should enter a send number");
       return;
    }
       else if ((x != 6 || x != 42 || x != 1042) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("you should enter a date send);
       return;
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no number can be both `6` and `42`, **every** number is different from either `6` or `42`, so your `if` statement **always** evaluates to true. I think you meant to use `&&` instead of `||` there:

```
if (x != 6 && x != 42 && x != 1042 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sn)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can improve the intention revealing of your code by creating a list, for example:

```
var dependsOnSendNumber = new [] {6, 42, 1042};
```

And then simply use a Linq query:

```
if (dependsOnSendNumber.Contains(x) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sn))
```

This improves readability, and you can make the dependsOnSendNumber list to be created dynamically accordingly to some rule. So, if anytime a new option is created that follows the same rule, the only thing you need to do is to set it accordingly to be included in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `int x = cmbExport.SelectedValue` because `mbExport.SelectedValue` return `String`